# UIRefreshControl Not Appearing

Tags: ios, uitableview, pull-to-refresh

I have a UITableView within my UIViewController. I'm trying to setup the UIRefreshControl pull to refresh feature. Below is my code.

```
// Within Class Itself
lazy var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action:
        #selector(MainViewController.refreshData),
                             for: .valueChanged)
    refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.darkGray

    return refreshControl
}()

// Within viewDidLoad
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    myTableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
} else {
    myTableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
}
```

But whenever I try to run it in the simulator and drag down on the table view nothing happens, and nothing is displayed. It's like the pull to refresh thing isn't being added to the table view.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which function contains the `if` statement?

Comment: @Paulw11 `viewDidLoad`

Comment: The code looks fine to me, same thing is working in my simulator. Tried both on iOS 9 and iOS 10+

Comment: Same code I tried on iOS 11, works for me as well.

Comment: May I know why you're doing a lazy initialization?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, this occurs because you have declared refreshControl with lazy initialisation. And you are adding refreshControl to tableview from out side of it.

Lazy will delay your refreshControl initialisation, but before that, refreshControl will be added to tableview, but here refreshControl is empty. So it doesn't work.

Try removing lazy, and direct initialisation(something like given below). I hope it'll work.

```
    var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action:
        #selector(MainViewController.refreshData),
                             for: .valueChanged)
    refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.darkGray

// Within viewDidLoad
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    myTableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
} else {
    myTableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
}
```

Comment: Haven't you forgot to connect your tableview property with storyboard tableview? please double check it. Otherwise there can't be any fault.

Comment: I just built a demo project and it works fine. I wonder if it has to do with [SwipeCellKit](https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit).

Comment: That can be, you should check demo project again by adding SwipeCellKit to it.